# evaluate filename with regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have a bit of code to evaluate a filename using a regex, this works fine, but I want to add in a 2<sup>nd</sup> pattern of `out_\d\d\d\d\d\d_` (then up to 150 character to hold an address).
Obviously I don't want to have `\d` 150 times, can anyone tell me the best way to to this?

thanks

```
REGEX_PATTERN = @"out_\d\d\d\d\d\d";

if (!Regex.Match(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(e.Name), REGEX_PATTERN).Success) {
  return;
}
```

Comment: I think this should work `\d{150}` [**`Link`**](http://regexlib.com/CheatSheet.aspx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1). I dont know regex just referred the link now only :)

Comment: is that `out_` followed by 6 digits and then *OPTIONALLY* followed by `_` and then 1-150 of any type of character?

Comment: yes, it can be either or, 6 digits or 6 digits followed by _ then 1 - 150 any alphanumeric, no spaces

Comment: Suggestion: to just check for a match use [`Regex.IsMatch`][http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.ismatch.aspx] which returns a boolean: true on match and false otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want:

```
REGEX_PATTERN = @"^out_\d{6}(?:_.{1,150})?$";
```

This breaks down as

```
`^`             - start of string
`out_\d{6}`     - `out_` followed by 6 digits
`(?:_.{1,50})?` - an optional string of _ followed by 1-150 characters
`$`             - end of string
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```
REGEX_PATTERN = @"out_\d{1,150}";
```

OR

```
// For strict boundary match
REGEX_PATTERN = @"^out_\d{1,150}$";
```

Comment: thanks for all the speedy answers, pity I cant accept them all!

Comment: That should be `REGEX_PATTERN = @"^out_\d{1,150}$";` otherwise it would match `fishout_345`

Comment: Thanks for suggestion! Probably this should be in place but i just focused on 150 limit of the question :)